# Not able to activate HTTP & HTTPS in google CLICK TO DEPLOY LAMP VM Instance

Tags: lamp, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am not able to activate HTTP for external IP of LAMP VM in google compute engine ... I just installed new LAMP server as VM Instance

and deployment was successfull and it also shown External IP .

When I wanted to enable Http for this VM but I am getting error

and its failing

"

> Invalid value for field 'resource.network': 'https://content.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/***********-4758/global/networks/default'. Must be the URL to a Compute resource of the correct type

(** hidden for privacy )

The Steps I followed

View your virtual machine instances in the Compute Engine instances page.
 1. In the External IP column, click the external IP address for your LAMP server name.
2. In the dialog box that opens, select the Allow HTTP traffic check box.
3. Click Apply to close the dialog box.

Comment: I tried many times following the steps mentioned in the tutorial  ( udate in the question steps I followed )

Comment: @Sam can you please tell where i went wrong , I just followed simple steps and not done any thing